# Storing per-object data for fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-buffer

I have a fragment shader that uses a few uniforms which are set on a per-object basis. Is there a way to store these uniforms on the graphics card somehow? I've heard of (but cannot find a tutorial for) vertex buffer objects--is there a trick to storing the information in there, so that I don't need to re-set the variables every time I draw a new object?

Each object has very few vertices, but they are completely static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are indeed Uniform Buffer Objects in later versions of OpenGL http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Uniform_Buffer_Object

Answer (score 1):

If you use the same shader program ID for all the objects, then you can just set the uniforms once before you render your objects as their value will stay the same until you set them again. So e.g. in your code where you load and compile the shader source, set the uniform variables that are common for all the objects, then render your objects, only setting the per-object uniforms.

The uniform buffer idea in one of the answers can be used if you have different shaders for different objects but you want to share some data between them. This is not necessary in your case as you mention a single shader.

Comment: What is an effect and what is a ContentManager? ;)

Comment: Oh crap I thought this was an XNA question there for a while :) Regardless, shader uniforms work the same, Editing the answer now :)